# Sending select values from form to php page

Tags: php, html

I have a html page with a select box with fixed values. I need to get those values to my php page to update my database. It works with a form with input fields.. Could you please look at my script and tell me what i'm doing wrong?

html select form:

```
<form action="opendicht.php" method="post">
        <select name="opendicht[]">
            <option name="open" value="open">open</option>
            <option name="dicht" value="dicht">dicht</option>
        </select>

        <input type="submit" value="Doorvoeren">
</form>
```

PHP page:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
include '../dbconnect.php';
//$connection = mysql_connect("", "", ""); // Establishing Connection with Server
//$db = mysql_select_db("cerar", $connection); // Selecting Database from Server
    if (isset($_POST['submit']))
    { // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
        $opendicht = $_POST['opendicht'];
        $open = $_POST['open'];
        $dicht = $_POST['dicht'];
        if ($open ='open' || $dicht ='dicht') {
            echo "it works";
        } else {
            echo "it won't work";
        }

    }   

    mysqli_close($con); // Closing Connection with Server
    //header( "refresh:5;url=device_toevoegen/device_toevoegen.php" );
?>
```

none of the echo's under the `if` or `else` will display on opendicht.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are checking if a $_POST['submit'] variable exists, but it doesn't on your form. You should name your submit button to make it exist :

```
<input type="submit" value="Doorvoeren" name="submit">
```

Also, you don't have to give a name to your options, just name your select and get the value then deal with it :

```
<select name="open">
    <option value="1">Open</option>
    <option value="0">Dicht</option>
</select>
```

Then in php

```
if(isset($_POST['open'])) {
    $open = (int) $_POST['open'];
    if ($open) {
        ...
    } else {
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace this

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

with

```
if(isset($_POST['opendicht']))
```

Check whether your input is present

Answer (score 0):

Here is your complete correct code.

HTML :

```
<form action="opendicht.php" method="post">
        <select name="opendicht" multiple>
            <option name="open" value="open">open</option>
            <option name="dicht" value="dicht">dicht</option>
        </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Doorvoeren" name="submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
include '../dbconnect.php';
//$connection = mysql_connect("", "", ""); // Establishing Connection with Server
//$db = mysql_select_db("cerar", $connection); // Selecting Database from Server
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    { // Fetching variables of the form which travels in URL
        $opendicht = $_POST['opendicht'];        
        if($opendicht ='open' || $opendicht ='dicht')
        {
            echo "it works";
        }
        else{
            echo "it won't work";
        }

    }   

    mysqli_close($con); // Closing Connection with Server
    //header( "refresh:5;url=device_toevoegen/device_toevoegen.php" );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative for this:

```
if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST) && count($_POST) > 0){
  //your code here
}
```